# Is it possible to have 2 pxe servers in the same subnet

Tags: pxe

We currently have one PXE server which is Novell ZENworks 11.3.1 for our Windows images.

We would like to deploy Ubuntu images. This is not possible with ZENworks. That's why we like to use FOG. This is also based on PXE.

Will it be possible to run both servers in the same subnet? Will it find 2 pxe servers so that you can chose?

Anybody any idea?

Comment: I believe you can.  You have to configure each dhcp server to manage the hosts.  If one dhcp server offers an ip to a host, the other one cannot.  Both servers listen, but make sure only one responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the meantime I found the solution.
It is possible, if you setup a small new server which does PXE Chain.

Via this way you can have multiple pxe servers. PXE chain will make sure you have a menu where you can choose between your PXE servers and forward to the chosen PXE server.

Answer (score 0):

Your router/L3 switch is the one which needs to handle this (if possible). Either by looking at IP/MAC addresses or some other logic. This question though, in my opinion has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to have multiple PXEs on one subnet. My guess is you'll have to use VLANs and also divide your network into two subnets.